# echo output not getting assigned to a variable in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, echo, cut

```
end=echo $FSDB_FILE_NAME | rev | cut -d'_' -f 2 |rev
begin=echo $FSDB_FILE_NAME | rev | cut -d'_' -f 3 |rev
echo $end
echo $begin

echo abc_11204.00_15713.00_.csv  | rev | cut -d'_' -f 2 |rev ---- This works
```

But echo $end is not printing anything

I even tried:

```
 set end=echo abc_11204.00_15713.00_.csv  | rev | cut -d'_' -f 2 |rev
 echo $end
```

This prints empty

Please help me with this

```
Sample input : abc_123.00_345.00_xyz.csv
Output : end=345.00
         begin=123.00
```

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts by showing your code. Could you please simply add sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: I am pretty sure once you add samples of input and expected output we could do it in a single command and could do in better approach too.

Comment: Samples added , please suggest a solution @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Easy approach with `awk`.

```
start=$(echo "$input_variable" | awk  -F'_' '{print $2}')
end=$(echo "$input_variable" | awk  -F'_' '{print $3}')
```

When I print variable's values it will be as follows:

```
echo "$start"
123.00
echo "$end"
345.00
```